# Prove that the shaded area is equal to $\frac{HA · HG}{2}$ without values

Tags: geometry, area

In the figure, $ABCDEF$ is a regular hexagon, $FGH$ is an equilateral triangle, and $F$ is a common vertex of both figures. If the sides of both figures are the same, prove that :

$$\Delta AFH + \Delta EFG = \frac{HA · HG}{2}$$

(consider that the position of $\Delta FGH$ doesn't matter)
[image]

***What i've done***
-The area of $\Delta FGH$ is $\frac{ABCDEF}{6}$
-Notice how $HAEG$ is a cyclic cuadrilateral so we can use ptolemy's theorem, so 
$$ HE·GA = HA · GE + HG · AE$$

but i don't really know if it's the correct way to apply it.

**Is it possible to do this exercise without any trigonometrical functions?**

Comment: The shaded area is $HG・AF$.

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: Since $AFH=EFG=$ right triangle. What are sides of both figures?

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Why $AFH=EFG$?

Comment: "both figures" is $HF=AF$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the picture $P\neq A$ is a point on the line $AF$ such that $|AF|=|PF|$. Also, by hypothesis $|AF|=|HF|$, which implies that $F$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle AHP$, so it is straight at $H$.

[image]

Now, observe that
$$\measuredangle PFH=\measuredangle PFG+\measuredangle GFH=\measuredangle PFG+\frac{\pi}3=\measuredangle PFG+\measuredangle EFP=\measuredangle EFG$$
Now, from the given hypothesis we have $|GF|=|FH|$ and $|EF|=|AF|$ and $|AF|=|PF|$ by construction, then $\triangle GEF$ and $\triangle HPF$ are equal.

I will use the notation $[\mathcal{A}]$ to denote the area of the figure $\mathcal{A}$, so
$$\text{Shaded area }=[AFH]+[EFG]=[AFH]+[HPF]=[AHP]=\frac{|HA|\cdot|HP|}{2}$$
And from $|HP|=|GE|$ we get
$$\text{Shaded area }=\frac{|HA|\cdot|GE|}{2}$$